# The github repo was already updated but it isn't being displayed in the domain in CI/CD

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, server, hosting

I have a project which have 2 repo and it is working well in my local.
But the change isn't working well in domain when I updated the code.
What happend?
Any tips will be thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue before, too.
This issue is because of a server issue.
Please clean your server cache.
Hope to solve your problem.
Cheers

Comment: No problem, it is my pleasure